# Восклицательный знак перед функцией - это значит её нужно немедленно выполнить?

Tags: javascript

```
! function(i) {
```

Восклицательный знак перед функцией - это значит её нужно немедленно выполнить?

Comment: откуда такие мысли у вас появились?

Comment: в интернете прочитал